# Can I simulate pressing the "Enter" key in Puppeteer using only a frame reference?

Tags: javascript, iframe, puppeteer

I'd really like to submit a form in an iframe using Puppeteer, which I've found I can do pretty easily by going

```js
page.keyboard.press('Enter');
```

However, for nearly everything else I want to do, all I need to pass around is a reference to the iframe I'm interested in. For instance, I may have a method that fills out and submits a form like so:

```js
// Some other setup script
const page = await context.newPage();
const frame = page.frames().find(frame => frame.name() === 'myFrame'); // Iframe ref

// Utility method
function useTheForm(frame) {

  // ...
  // Do other misc form setup  
  // ...

  await frame.type('myInput', 'Some Value');

  // TODO: Submit the form... somehow...
  // "frame.keyboard" doesn't exist. Need some kind of ref like "frame.page"
  // frame._frameManager._page.keyboard.press('Enter') works, but is kind of dirty...
}

// Use our utility method
useTheForm(frame);
```

I'd really like a way to submit the form using the "Enter" key without having to also keep track of and pass around a reference to `page` as well, but I'm hesitant to use intended-to-be-internal properties that aren't documented in the API.

Answer (score 0):

You can focus an element in the iframe and then press a key with `page.keyboard`. Here is an example that press Enter on a focused link in an iframe causing iframe navigation (though this navigation seems failed due to site iframe policy):

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async function main() {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch(
      { headless: false, defaultViewport: null });
    const [page] = await browser.pages();

    await page.goto('https://example.org/');

    const data = await page.evaluate(() => {
      document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('iframe')).src =
        'https://example.org/?foo=bar';
    });

    await page.waitFor(3000);
    console.log(page.frames().map(frame => frame.url()));
    await page.frames()[1].focus('a');
    await page.keyboard.press('Enter');

    //await browser.close();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```